# In Unity 2D how to prevent CircleCollider2D stays on another one?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity 2D, if I drop `CircleCollider2D` just at the same x position, then it stays on another one like the image shows. How can I prevent this?

(If I dropped one just a little bit away onto the yellow one then all of them fell.)

[image]

I can think of some hacks such as place the ball a little bit away from where the player place it randomly, or give it a minor random force when balls collides with each other. I just wonder if there's a neat way such as some physic engine related parameters such as fraction/drag that I'm not familiar with that you can set to prevent this "seemingly unnatual result".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well instead of making it possible to drop the ball at exactly the right spot,
Simply do not allow this action to the user and always drop the ball slightly to the left or right of the ball.

You could probably use a raycast straight down to check if this is the case (only when the two centre circles are aligned).

Comment: Thank you. This is a solution, but seems like a hack to me. I wonder if there's a built in or more "proper" way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to prevent this behaviour? This is exactly how balls are supposed to behave in a 2D enviroment. If you want the balls to fall, just provide a little offset on the x-axis, or do not give the player the option to place them perfectly lined up (this of course depends on what kind of game you are working on).

Comment: Thank you. I feel it is unnatural that you can easily drop many balls and all of them lined up perfectly. I wonder if there's a built-in and less "hack" way to prevent this.

Comment: @ArtS While I do not know about any built-in features, I am sure you will easily be able to code a "slippery" behaviour yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I tried play with some parameters but nothing worked. Seems probably there's nothing built-in related. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ArtS Indeed, this is the expected behaviour. There is no built-in function or option inside the editor to make it behave like you want. You need to implement the behaviour yourself, either by giving a slight offset on the x axis or applying some minor force. A minimal offset or force should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following codes to solve it:

When two ball collides with each other, call the following method on both of them.

```
public void AddRandomMinorForce()
{
    if (!randomForceUsed)
    {
        randomForceUsed = true;
        var x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
        var y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
        var direction = new Vector3(x, y, 0f);
        rb.AddForce(direction * 10);
    }
}
```